# building a Jquery Tool slider like yahoo.com slider details

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-tools

Hi im trying to achieve a "news slider" like the one you can see in yahoo.com... I almost have the 100% of the code.. (if you want to compare them here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/PcAwU/1/)

what is missing in my code , (forget about design) is that , In my slider you have to clic on each item, i tried to replace Onclick for Hover on the javascript, it worked, but the fisrt image on the gallery stop working, so when you just open the slider, you see a missing image.

Other point.. also very important, in yahoo.com after "x seconds" the slider goes to the next item, and so on ... all the Thumnails are gruped 4 by for 4, (in mine 5 by 5, thats ok) ... after pass all the 4 items, it go to the next bloc..

HOW CAN I ACHIEVE THAT!!. I really looked into the API, everything, really im lost, i hope someone can help me. cause im really lost in here.

Thanks

Here is the script

```
$(function() {
var root = $(".scrollable").scrollable({circular: false}).autoscroll({ autoplay: true });

$(".items img").click(function() {
    // see if same thumb is being clicked
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) { return; }

    // calclulate large image's URL based on the thumbnail URL (flickr specific)
    var url = $(this).attr("src").replace("_t", "");

    // get handle to element that wraps the image and make it semi-transparent
    var wrap = $("#image_wrap").fadeTo("medium", 0.5);

    // the large image from www.flickr.com
    var img = new Image();


    // call this function after it's loaded
    img.onload = function() {

        // make wrapper fully visible
        wrap.fadeTo("fast", 1);

        // change the image
        wrap.find("img").attr("src", url);

    };

    // begin loading the image from www.flickr.com
    img.src = url;

    // activate item
    $(".items img").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

// when page loads simulate a "click" on the first image
}).filter(":first").click();

// provide scrollable API for the action buttons
window.api = root.data("scrollable");

});


function toggle(el){
    if(el.className!="play")
    {
        el.className="play";
         el.src='images/play.png';
        api.pause();
    }
    else if(el.className=="play")
    {
        el.className="pause";
         el.src='images/pause.png';
        api.play();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the hover problem you need to make some quick changes: Change the click to a on(..) similar to just hover(..) just the new standard.

```
$(".items img").on("hover",function() {
....
```

Then You need to update the bottom click event to mouse over to simulate a hover effect. Trigger is a comman function to use to trigger some event.

```
}).filter(":first").trigger("mouseover");
```

jSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PcAwU/2/

---

Now to have a play feature, you need a counter/ and a set interval like so:

```
var count = 1;
setInterval(function(){
    count++; // add to the counter
    if($(".items img").eq(count).length != 0){ // eq(.. select by index [0],[1]..
        $(".items img").eq(count).trigger("mouseover");
    } else count = 0; //reset counter
},1000);
```

This will go show new images every 1 second (1000 = 1sec), you can change this and manipulate it to your liking.

jSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PcAwU/3/

---

If you want to hover the active image, you need to do so with the `css()` or the `addClass()` functions. But You have done this already, All we have to do is a simple css change:

```
.scrollable .active {
    ....
    border-bottom:3px solid skyblue;
```

Here is the new update jSFilde: http://jsfiddle.net/PcAwU/4/

Comment: Great! it worked, do you have any idea about the other point, ??

Comment: @DreaminMediaQueretaro Added it to the question.

Comment: is on the question this part..... Other point.. also very important, in yahoo.com after "x seconds" the slider goes to the next item, and so on ... all the Thumnails are gruped 4 by for 4, (in mine 5 by 5, thats ok) ... after pass all the 4 items, it go to the next bloc..

HOW CAN I ACHIEVE THAT!!.

Comment: @DreaminMediaQueretaro Sorry, I can't understand what you mean by that question

Comment: Sorry its my bad english.. if you go to yahoo.com you will see a slider.. in that slider, the "ACTIVE" item is in a blue color, each 5 seconds i think the next image or item is selected as active.. and after 5 seconds the next image.. This is automatic no need of hover or clic or anything. cheers

Comment: @DreaminMediaQueretaro Have you not seen my example I have up in my question above? Is that wrong? It changes images every 1 seconds (dont hover over anything) Look at my question, I have added more things to it and tell me if its wrong.

Comment: NO its very nice actually!!, i just see it, i just have a question here, Now everything is working, but how do i set a CSS style or class, or ID, to modify the appearence of the active item.. i think you insert this class, via java, am i wrong?.. By the way, .... Are you the best or what.

Comment: @DreaminMediaQueretaro Updated question. Look above.

Comment: @Jessica Girl I love your code, i take a part im trying to achieve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825046/build-prev-next-button-on-jquery-for-images-inside-overlay pls help!!! i see you are a expert on jquerytools, pls HEEEELP! jajaja im desperate!! no one answer this!!!