# Prev & Next button with counter for overlay using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

I build this image gallery using jquerytools, I'm using scrollable div on thumbs and overlay on the main image... Everything works like charm..

EDIT: Before I make this a bounty...I have to explain that I need something clean and simple like this, because the images come from php (encrypted) , and I can't modify this, just the "view" as I need to achieve this with something like classes and ids. This is why I try this but...

The problem is I need to insert a Next and Prev Buttons when you are viewing the overlay... so you can go trough the images, once the overlay has been loaded..

I have made this fiddle for you my teachers full of wisdom can see what I am saying. http://jsfiddle.net/s6TGs/5/

I have really tried. but api.next() it's working for the scrolling on the thumbs , so I don't know how can I tell this script.. hey if next is clicked, yo pls insert next url on thubs, if previous btn is clicked, pls go to prev url on thumbs.. But I can't

Also and no less important a Counter like 1/8 have to be displayed =S... how in the name of JavaScript you do this..

Here is My code

```
$(function() {
$(".scrollable").scrollable();

$(".items img").click(function() {
    // see if same thumb is being clicked
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) { return; }

    // calclulate large image's URL based on the thumbnail URL (flickr specific)
    var url = $(this).attr("src").replace("_t", "");

    // get handle to element that wraps the image and make it semi-transparent
    var wrap = $("#image_wrap").fadeTo("medium", 0.5);
    var wrap2 = $("#mies1");

    // the large image from www.flickr.com
    var img = new Image();

    // call this function after it's loaded
    img.onload = function() {

        // make wrapper fully visible
        wrap.fadeTo("fast", 1);

        // change the image
        wrap.find("img").attr("src", url);
        wrap2.find("img").attr("src", url);

    };

    // begin loading the image from www.flickr.com
    img.src = url;

    // activate item
    $(".items img").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

// when page loads simulate a "click" on the first image
}).filter(":first").click();
});

// This makes the image Overlay with a div and html

  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("img[rel]").overlay({

      // some mask tweaks suitable for modal dialogs
      mask: {
        color: '#ebecff',
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.9
      },

      closeOnClick: true
  });
});
```

I know here is part of my answer I just can make it work :(

http://jquerytools.org/demos/combine/portfolio/index.html

EDIT: Thanks to the first answer by QuakeDK I almost achieve the goal.. But the counter is not ok, also when you get to the 4 image (number 5 on counter) you cant go to the 5th thumb .. This is the CODE with that answer integrated

http://jsfiddle.net/xHL35/5/

And here is the CODE for PREV & NEXT BUTTON

```
//NExt BTN

  $(".nextImg").click(function(){
            // Count all images
            var count = $(".items img").length;

            var next = $(".items").find(".active").next("img");
            if(next.is(":last")){
                next = $(".items").find(".active").parent().next("div").find("img:first");
                if(next.index() == -1){
                    // We have reached the end - start over.
                    next = $(".items img:first");
                    scrollapi.begin(200);
                } else {
                    scrollapi.next(200);
                }
            }

            // Get the current image number
            var current = (next.index("img"));

            var nextUrl = next.attr("src").replace("_t", "");

            // get handle to element that wraps the image and make it semi-transparent
            var wrap = $("#image_wrap").fadeTo("medium", 0.5);
            var wrap2 = $("#mies1");

            // the large image from www.flickr.com
            var img = new Image();

            // call this function after it's loaded
            img.onload = function() {
                // make wrapper fully visible
                wrap.fadeTo("fast", 1);

                // change the image
                wrap.find("img").attr("src", nextUrl);
                wrap2.find("img").attr("src", nextUrl);
            };

            // begin loading the image from www.flickr.com
            img.src = nextUrl;

            $("#imageCounter").html("Image: "+current+" of "+count);

            // activate item
            $(".items img").removeClass("active");
            next.addClass("active");

        });

  //PREV BTN

    $(".prevImg").click(function(){
            // Count all images
            var count = $(".items img").length;

            var prev = $(".items").find(".active").prev("img");
            if(prev.is(":first")){
                prev = $(".items").find(".active").parent().prev("div").find("img:first");
                if(prev.index() == -1){
                    // We have reached the end - start over.
                    prev = $(".items img:first");
                    scrollapi.begin(200);
                } else {
                    scrollapi.prev(200);
                }
            }

            // Get the current image number
            var current = (prev.index("img"));

            var prevUrl = prev.attr("src").replace("_t", "");

            // get handle to element that wraps the image and make it semi-transparent
            var wrap = $("#image_wrap").fadeTo("medium", 0.5);
            var wrap2 = $("#mies1");

            // the large image from www.flickr.com
            var img = new Image();

            // call this function after it's loaded
            img.onload = function() {
                // make wrapper fully visible
                wrap.fadeTo("fast", 1);

                // change the image
                wrap.find("img").attr("src", prevUrl);
                wrap2.find("img").attr("src", prevUrl);
            };

            // begin loading the image from www.flickr.com
            img.src = prevUrl;

            $("#imageCounter").html("Image: "+current+" of "+count);

            // activate item
            $(".items img").removeClass("active");
            prev.addClass("active");    
        });
```

There must be a reward option here, if somebody help me I give you 20box! jajaja I'm desperate. Because now I also need to display title for each image, and I think it's the same process of URL replace, but next & prev is just something I can't manage.. Post the full solution and your email on paypal, I will pay 20!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, never tried jQueryTOOLS, so thought it would be fun to play with.

first of all, here's the JSFiddle I just created: http://jsfiddle.net/xHL35/1/

Now, the API calls need a variable to hold it

```
 $(".scrollable").scrollable();
 var scrollapi = $(".scrollable").data("scrollable");
```

Now scrollapi, can call the functions like this:

```
scrollapi.next(200);
```

I've copied your own code for choosing image and just rewritten it to fit the NEXT image.
I haven't created the PREV function, but should not be that hard to reverse the NEXT function.

```
$(".nextImg").click(function(){
    // Count all images
    var count = $(".items img").length;

    // Finding the next image
    var next = $(".items").find(".active").next("img");
    // Is the next image, the last image in the wrapper?
    if(next.is(":last")){
        // If it is, go to next DIV and get the first image
        next = $(".items").find(".active").parent().next("div").find("img:first");
        // If this dosn't exists, we've reached the end
        if(next.index() == -1){
          // We have reached the end - start over.
          next = $(".items img:first");
          scrollapi.begin(200);
        } else {
          // Not at the end, show next div in thumbs
          scrollapi.next(200);
        }
    }

    // Get the current image number
    var current = (next.index("img"));

    var nextUrl = next.attr("src").replace("_t", "");

    // get handle to element that wraps the image and make it semi-transparent
    var wrap = $("#image_wrap").fadeTo("medium", 0.5);
    var wrap2 = $("#mies1");

    // the large image from www.flickr.com
    var img = new Image();

    // call this function after it's loaded
    img.onload = function() {
      // make wrapper fully visible
      wrap.fadeTo("fast", 1);
      // change the image
      wrap.find("img").attr("src", nextUrl);
      wrap2.find("img").attr("src", nextUrl);
    };

    // begin loading the image from www.flickr.com
    img.src = nextUrl;

    // Show the counter
    $("#imageCounter").html("Image: "+current+" of "+count);

    // activate item
    $(".items img").removeClass("active");
    next.addClass("active");

});
```

Hoping you can use this to develop the rest of the gallery.

Comment: You are my hero!!! but you missunderstood one part, and im really sorry, sure was my bad english.. I need the NExt and Prev inside the "pop" or "main image" as i call it... so once it "pops" you can go trough all images (not outside de "pop"):D (thanks really its awesome, im sure i cant even do what yo just did!

Comment: And i will need to style them isnt better to use a normal <a href>

Comment: I just move the button and still works even inside the Overlay, pls let me know how can i change it to normal <a href> and i hope i can manage to do prev function. http://jsfiddle.net/xHL35/2/ . If no better answer is given you are the winner pal

Comment: @JulesMartinez Just change it to: <a href="javascript:();" class="nextImg">NEXT</a> and it should work as a link also.

Comment: @JulesMartinez and thank you, loves to help :) throw a comment if the PREV dosn't do as you say :)

Comment: really appreciate your words, and sharing wisdow..here you can see my prev code, i really try :( http://jsfiddle.net/xHL35/4/ , its at the bottom you will find it below the code you insert.

Comment: And just one more question, why the counter says 12 images?, ajaja and why if i direct pop 3er thumb the counter is not set to 3.. how can i do that?

Comment: I can wait until tomorrow, the point of SO is that the answer is public, maybe this helps someone else, i will try to fix prev function until then thanks!!!!

Comment: Thanks to you i almost got it.. pls just help me fix the counter , prev button is now working http://jsfiddle.net/xHL35/5/

Comment: @JulesMartinez - Actually there are 12 images, that's why the count. I've updated some css so you can see the `next` & `prev` buttons on the slider, and JS to scroll accordingly, hope this solves your issues: http://jsfiddle.net/xHL35/7/

Comment: This is so great!!!, Its working on the PHP site actually now, =) thanks to you, i just found a new problem, this line wrap2.find("img").attr("src", url);  Seek for all images inside the wrap2 div... Can i "Omit" or "exclude" a div so the images there are not replaced for the current image... because all the images on the overlay ,even buttons are replaced for the current overlayed image..

Comment: DO you know why when i insert this code here produce an error, i tried to disable jquery.min.js but i still get this errors http://queretaro.orsilin.com.mx/index.php?page=item/view/15/Probando

Comment: @JulesMartinez Just took a look, guessing you've fixed it? Because I can't see anything wrong.